# SQL ERROR mysql_fetch_array(): not valid?

Tags: php, mysql

I just can't figure out why i get  the error message, I have tried removing the'' and the()

I have run the script in phpmyadmin and it says the problem with my syntax is at $result = ("SELECT * FROM 'test_prefixCatagory' ORDER by 'Cat'");

```
$result = ("SELECT * FROM 'test_prefixCatagory' ORDER by 'Cat'");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

$sCat = ($row['Cat']);
$sCatID = ($row['CatID']);
{
echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr valign='top'><td><b><a href='#".$sCat."'>".$sCat."</a></b><br>";
 // column 1 categories
 $result2 = ("SELECT * FROM `test_prefixSubCat` WHERE `CatID`=$sCatID");
 // sub-cats
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
    {
  $sSub = ($row2['CatID']);
  $sSubID = ($row2['SubID']);
  echo "<dd><a href='#'>".$sSub."</a><br>";

 }

 echo "<br></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
 }
```

Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: You should no longer listen to the one that told you to put brackets around everything like `($row2['CatID'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test_prefixCatagory ORDER by `Cat`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$sCat = $row['Cat'];
$sCatID = $row['CatID'];
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr valign='top'><td><b><a href='#" . $sCat . "'>" . $sCat . "</a></b><br>";
// column 1 categories
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test_prefixSubCat` WHERE `CatID`='".$sCatID. "'");
// sub-cats
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $sSub = $row2['CatID'];
    $sSubID = $row2['SubID'];
    echo "<dd><a href='#'>" . $sSub . "</a><br>";

    }

        echo "<br></td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: actually both results need fixing according to d4rkpr1nc3's suggestion

Comment: yes, sorry, i've stop looking down after seeing the first line

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_prefixCatagory ORDER by Cat");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr valign='top'><td><b><a href='#".$row['Cat']."'>".$row['Cat']."</a></b><br>";

$sCatID = ($row['CatID']);
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_prefixSubCat WHERE CatID=$sCatID");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
$sSub = ($row2['CatID']);
$sSubID = ($row2['SubID']);
echo "<dd><a href='#'>".$row2['Sub']."</a><br>";
Had to rearrange a few things in it. Now its working, your answer helped thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = ("SELECT * FROM `test_prefixCatagory` ORDER by `Cat`");
```

Comment: the "`" character is only necesary when tables or column names are sql keywords (values, relations, keys, rows, columns, order etc.).

Comment: yes its strongly necessary in case of keywords, but harmless at all

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you need to add `mysql_query` but you also need to remove the single quotes from the table name and field name. You can use backticks if you wish but **not single quotes around table names**.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test_prefixCatagory` ORDER by `Cat`");

// other query:
 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test_prefixSubCat` WHERE `CatID`=$sCatID");
```

When debugging MySQL problems, use `mysql_error()` to see a description of the problem.